# how to fetch N most recent items but sort them in ascending order using NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to create an NSFetchRequest to fetch the most recent 80 items from my entity and sort them in ascending order.

Is it possible to achieve this in one request?  Currently I am doing two requests.  One to get the date of the most recent item offset by 80 and then using that date in the second request.

What I want to achieve is:

```
let request:NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemTimestamp", ascending: false)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemGroupId == %@", self.itemGroupId)

request.fetchLimit = 80

// add logic to sort the returned results in ascending: true
```

Comment: Use one request and [reverse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed) the order of the result.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to achieve this purely from the fetch request.  I don't want to be sorting larger arrays after the fetch

Comment: 80 items is not really large  It’s not possible in one request.

Comment: thx.  I know 80 is not large but subsequent requests increase by 80 each time and can go up to many thousands.

Comment: Why don't you just access current results in reverse order, for example, if you're using `UITableView` to display the fetch result, access your array like this: `let item = result[result.count - indexPath.item - 1]`. Also, `reversed()` method is lazy (but it is not implicitly lazy when you apply algorithms, such as `map`, to its results)